# How to properly convert radians to degrees

Tags: python-3.x

```
angle1 = input("Enter the angle: ")
angle1 = float(angle1)
opp = input("Enter the opp side: ")
opp = float(opp)
answer = math.tan(math.degrees(angle1))
answer = float(answer)
adj = answer * opp
print(adj)

Enter the angle: 45
Enter the opp side: 5
-6.810224381304188
```

on the 45-45-90 angle the adj should be 5, I have checked my math and have the correct math but I don't know why it prints out 6.8 instead of 5

Comment: `import math; math.degrees(math.pi/4)` returns `45`. `math.degrees()` converts radians into degrees, not the opposite.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes, for what the OP means to do, calculate the tangent, he needs to apply `math.radians` to his input value in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
import math
angle1 = input("Enter the angle: ")
angle1 = float(angle1)
opp = input("Enter the opp side: ")
opp = float(opp)
# answer = math.tan((angle1*math.pi)/180)

answer = math.tan(math.radians(angle1))
answer = float(answer)
adj = answer * opp
# print(math.ceil(adj))
print(round(adj))
```